# Why isn't the link's color changing when I hover above its parent li?

Tags: html, css

I've got a simple html-list which contains elements like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="http://somecool url.com/">some link</a>
   <span class="sc-track-duration">24.27</span>
</li>
```

On the hover-state I change the text-color to white:

```
li:hover {
   background-color: #d21600;
   color: #fff;
}
```

The span's text-color changes but the link's color doesn't.

How can I solve this without using JS?

Comment: The html for the anchor tag is wrong, missing a ">" and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style the anchor as well, for example:

```
li:hover, li:hover a {
   background-color: #d21600;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Your anchor has a more specific style defined elsewhere and that's winning, even over your `li:hover` rule, so you need to add a more specific `li:hover a` to get it styled as well.

Comment: In addition to this I'd also recommend checking that you have a DOCTYPE defined.

Comment: It only colors the link in this case when I hover over the link. It may happen that I hover the li, but not the link.

Comment: @Hedge - It seems you still have a style defined somewhere else that applies to that `<a>` that has more specificity...can you look in Firebug for example and see what style that is applying to that `<a>`, or have a link to the page?

Comment: Look at the tracklist of the custom soundcloud player in the sidebar of http://www.ali.dj .I want the link's text to become white when you hover over a track.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add the style to the `a` element within the `li`, you can do that by simply do this:

```
li:hover, li:hover a {
   background-color: #d21600;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It only colors the link in this case when I hover over the link. It may happen that I hover the li, but not the link.

Answer (score 2):

You know the exact code you posted is wrong. Missing "> there.

```
<li>
   <a href="http://somecool url.com/">link text</a>
   <span class="sc-track-duration">24.27</span>
</li>
```